# Migration of test case from test rail to azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, migration, testrail

Currently my organization is using test rail as our test management system and we are planning to move to azure devops. Is there any easy way to move all my existing 1500 test case to azure devops? We also have some attachments in our test case in test rail.

Is only the excel import only option or we do have any utility to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find a tool to do the migration smoothly. However, both `Test Rail` and `Azure DevOps` support exporting and importing test cases from CSV or Excel.

So, the excel import option should be the way you can check, you may need to adjust and format your CSV(s) to Import.

See [Test Rail - Import test cases from CSV or Excel](https://support.gurock.com/hc/en-us/articles/7101779988372-Import-test-cases-from-CSV-or-Excel#prepare-your-source-file-to-import-0-0) and [Bulk import or export test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/copy-clone-test-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#bulk-import-or-export-test-cases) for details.